# Summarizing table into multiple fields using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, summarizing

I have a large table with 150000 features. Every feature has one key and a keyword that I want to use to make a new field with. Below is an example:

```
|Field A|Field b|Shape_area|
|key 1  |Type 1 |300       |
|key 1  |Type 2 |4500      |
|key 2  |Type 1 |100       |
|key 2  |Type 1 |300       |
```

I want to summarize it like this:

```
|KEY  |TYPE 1|TYPE 2|
|Key 1|300   |4500  |
|Key 2|400   |0     |
```

Is this possible in ArcGIS Pro?

I've tried the summarize statistics, but I only get the keys in a long table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Pivot table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/pivot-table.htm) with FieldA as Input Field, Field B as Pivot Field and Area as Value Field:
   [image]
2. Then use [Summary Statistics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm) with type1 and 2 as statistics fields and field a as case field:
   [image]

Or use python pandas module:

```py
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\table'
fieldA = 'Field A'
fieldB = 'Field B'
area = 'Shape_area'

fieldlist = [fieldA,fieldB,area]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fieldlist), columns=fieldlist)
table = pd.pivot_table(data=df, values=area, index=fieldA, columns=fieldB, 
                      aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
table.to_clipboard()
```

Comment: The OP requested a solution in ArcGIS Pro -- would you be able to duplicate this procedure using that version?

Comment: Yes I know. I dont post solutions that does not work.

Comment: Thank you very much @BERA. The pivot table tool was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Taking @BERA's solution and providing ArcGIS Pro Desktop interface examples:

[image]

**1. Use the Pivot Table Data Management Tool**

- Field A = Input Field
- Field B = Pivot Field
- Shape Area = Value Field

[image]

[image]

[image]

**2. Use the "Summary Stastistics" Analysis tool:**

- Statistics Fields = Type 1 (Statistics Type Sum) & Type 2 (Statistics
  Type Sum)
- Case Field = Field A

[image]

**Final Results:**

[image]

**Personal notes about the process:** Although this solution does provide the desired results, it does create some "waste" as we need to create a intermediary table in order to utilize the Summary Statistics tool to get the final results. Essentially the Pivot Table has a single use and then after that it takes up space. If this is something that is done on a regular basis, I would recommend creating a Model which stores the Pivot Table in memory.

Comment: You can store temporary tables in [memory workspace](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/the-in-memory-workspace.htm).